# How do you make an Image View a Hyperlink on the iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiimageview, hyperlink

My question is this: in many free iPhone apps adds which are basically imageViews are buttons. When pressed, they bring you to the iphone App store to buy whichever app was advertised. Can this be tweaked to open a hyperlink in the iphone's safari browser? and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The App Store links are already simple hyperlinks, but the system notices that they point to the app store and opens the App Store app right away. The links are opened using the [`openURL:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL:) method of the `UIApplication` class:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com/"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: so should I put this under an IBAction, and make the imageView a Button?